# All homomorphisms from $U(10) $ to $\mathbb{Z}_8$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

To find all homomorphisms, it suffices to map a generator of $U(10)$ to some element in $\mathbb{Z}_8$. We can note that 3 generates $U(10)$ so we have 8 options to choose from in $\mathbb{Z}_8$. So there are 8 homomorphisms.

However, the hint on my textbook says that there are only 4. Could someone explain why?

Comment: Every generator of $U(10)$ has order $4$ hence the image of $3$ cannot be an element of order $8$ of $\mathbb Z_8$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\mathbb{Z}_8$ has a unique group of order $d$, where $d$ is any divisor of $8$. Indeed any finite cyclic group $G$ has a unique subgroup of order $d$, where $d \mid |G|$. Now obviously the image of the group $U(10) \cong \mathbb{Z}_4$ must be the unique subgroup of order $4,2$ or $1$ of $\mathbb{Z}_8$.

For the first case there are two possibilities, as the subgroup of order $4$ has $\phi(4) = 2$ generators. Those homomorphisms are induced by $3 \to \bar{2}$ and $3 \to \bar{6}$.

For the second case we get that we have a single option, namely the homomorphism induced by $3 \to \bar{4}$.

Finally you have the trivial homomorphism induced by $3 \to \bar{0}$

---

You can also notice that the image of $\phi: \mathbb{Z}_n \to \mathbb{Z}_m$ is included in the unique subgroup $\mathbb{Z}_{\gcd(m,n)}$ of $\mathbb{Z}_m$. Now $\mathbb{Z}_n$ can be mapped to any subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_{\gcd(m,n)}$, as every subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is normal, so by Correspondence Theorem it is a kernel of such a mapping.

Now subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_{\gcd(m,n)}$ are of the form $\mathbb{Z}_d$, where $d \mid \gcd(m,n)$. Each of those has exactly $\phi(d)$ generators, so there are $\phi(d)$ homomorphisms to $\mathbb{Z}_d$. So finally the wanted number of homomorphisms is:

$$\sum_{k=1; gcd(d,\gcd(m,n)) \not = 1}^{\gcd(m,n)} \phi(k) = \gcd(m,n)$$

The last identity is well-known one and in general its true that $\sum_{k=1; gcd(d,s) \not = 1}^{s} \phi(k) = s$

Comment: Ok, this also works on other groups, right? Or is it a characteristic property in $\mathbb{Z_k}$ for some k?

Comment: @mandella I added some more explanation to go with the answer. Anyway the number of such homomorphisms depends hugely on the structure of the groups in question and I don't think there's an easy answer.