# Construct a non trivial homomorphism $\mathbb Z_{14} \to\mathbb Z_{21}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, integers, group-homomorphism

**Question :**

> Construct a non trivial homomorphism from the group $\mathbb Z_{14}$ to the group $\mathbb Z_{21}$.

**Discussion :**

So, to start off, we see that the orders of the given groups for the homomorphism, are :

$$|\mathbb Z_{14}|=14$$

$$|\mathbb Z_{21}|=21$$

Then, if $φ : \mathbb Z_{14} \to \mathbb Z_{21}$ is a homomorphism, $|φ[\mathbb Z_{14}]|$ should divide both $|\mathbb Z_{14}|$ and $|\mathbb Z_{21}|=21$. The common divisors of $14$ and $21$ are $1$ and $7$ which means that **there exists** a non-trivial homomorphism.

Would this also mean that $|φ[\mathbb Z_{14}]| = 7$ ?

**How would one proceed after the initial criteria elaborated, to construct a homomorphism as asked though and give a complete answer to the question ?** I can't seem to determine a specific one. I know that $\mathbb Z_{14}$ is the group of integers $\mod 14$ and $\mathbb Z_{21}$ is the group of integers $\mod 21$.

Comment: One would proceed the same way as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2593331/all-homomorphisms-from-u10-to-mathbbz-8).

Comment: Maybe you can use $\mathbb{Z}_{14} = \mathbb{Z}_{7} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{2}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{21} = \mathbb{Z}_{7} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{3}$

Comment: @openspace So, the $\mathbb Z_7$ parts are homomorphic to each other and I need to specify something to be a homomorphism between $\mathbb Z_2$ and $\mathbb Z_3$ ?

Comment: Check that $\varphi([k]) = [3k]$ defines a homomorphism. The formula is inspired by the observations you make about orders. I don't know why the answers below need to appeal to the chinese remainder theorem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By the Chinese remainder Theorem, $\Bbb Z_{14}\cong\Bbb Z_7\oplus \Bbb Z_2$. Concretely, this map is given by mapping any element $a+14\Bbb Z\in\Bbb Z_{14}$ to $(a+7\Bbb Z, a+2\Bbb Z)$. Similarly, there is an isomorphism $\Bbb Z_7\oplus \Bbb Z_3\cong\Bbb Z_{21}$. This map is given by mapping $(a+7\Bbb Z,b+3\Bbb Z)$ to $(15a-14b)+21\Bbb Z$.

We want to use the homomorphism $\Bbb Z_{14}\to\Bbb Z_{21}$ induced by the homomorphism
\begin{align*}
\Bbb Z_7 \oplus \Bbb Z_2 &\longrightarrow \Bbb Z_7 \oplus \Bbb Z_3 \\
(x,y) &\longmapsto (x,0)
\end{align*}
which is nontrivial. According to the above concrete description of both CRT isomorphisms, we can describe it as follows:
\begin{align*}
f: \Bbb Z_{14} &\longrightarrow \Bbb Z_{21} \\
 a+14\Bbb Z &\longmapsto 15a+21\Bbb Z
\end{align*}
This one is nontrivial. You can also check directly that it is a homomorphism.

**Edit.** To elaborate further on the concrete descriptions of these isomorphisms, let us discuss this slightly more abstractly. Let $p$ and $q$ be prime numbers and $n:=pq$. In our case, we have $p=7$ and $q$ is either $2$ or $3$. The [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) gives you $s,t\in\Bbb{Z}$ with $tp+sq=1$. Given this, the isomorphisms are as follows:
\begin{align*}
\phi:\Bbb{Z}_n&\longrightarrow\Bbb{Z}_p\oplus\Bbb{Z}_q &
\psi=\phi^{-1}:\Bbb{Z}_p\oplus\Bbb{Z}_q&\longrightarrow\Bbb{Z}_n \\
(a+n\Bbb{Z})&\longmapsto((a+p\Bbb{Z}),(a+q\Bbb{Z})) &
((a+p\Bbb{Z}),(b+q\Bbb{Z})) &\longmapsto (btp+asq+n\Bbb{Z})
\end{align*}
This works because 
$$
\phi(\psi(a+p\Bbb{Z},b+q\Bbb{Z}))=\phi(btp+asq+n\Bbb{Z})
 = (asq+p\Bbb{Z},btp+q\Bbb{Z})=(a+p\Bbb{Z},b+q\Bbb{Z}),
$$
where the final equality follows from $tp+sq=1$, because it translates to
\begin{align*}
tp&\equiv 1\mod q, \\
sq&\equiv 1\mod p.
\end{align*}
Now in the case $p=7$ and $q=3$, we have $t=-2$ and $s=5$, because $-14+15=1$. I hope this clarifies the construction of the map.

Comment: @Rebellos By the way, see [the construction for the inverse in CRT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Existence_(constructive_proof)) to see how I came up with the explicit description of $\Bbb Z_7\oplus \Bbb Z_3\cong\Bbb Z_{21}$.

Comment: Could you please explain why you construct the first mapping using only $a$ and the 2nd mapping using $a$ and $b$ and where do $15a - 14b $ come from ?

Comment: @JeskoHüttenhain i have the same question with MarwanB.Could you elaborate more?

Comment: @MarwanB, does my edit explain sufficiently?

Comment: @JeskoHüttenhain Great explanation, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Recall that $\Bbb Z_n\oplus \Bbb Z_m\cong \Bbb Z_{nm}$ if and only if $n$ and $m$ are coprime.

$$\Bbb Z_2\oplus \Bbb Z_7\to \Bbb Z_3\oplus \Bbb Z_7$$
is a morphism between two semisimple $\Bbb Z$-modules. Of course the image of this morphism is also a semisimple module, in which case it is an isomorphism, or it is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_3$ or $\Bbb Z_7$, else it is trivial. They have different cardinalities, so it is clear they are not isomorphic.

One can then easily take for example $\phi((a,b))=(0,b)$ which yields an isomorphism of the submodule $\Bbb Z_7$ within both of these.